# VB.Net JSON data import

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I am a teacher who has been given a subject teaching Digital Solutions. While I have experience in VB.net and VBA, I have not had experience with JSON.

I would like to use the data based on the URL in the code below.
If someone could assist with the code and add some annotations (notes) as to what specific lines do, this would be helpful. The code below is what I have tried to discover by myself from the internet and may be partially incorrect (especially the "Case" section).`enter code here`

```
Option Strict On
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Linq
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Public Class WeatherMain

Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim reader As StreamReader
    Dim Sec1 As String

    Try

        request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://www.data.qld.gov.au/datastore/dump/2bbef99e-9974-49b9-a316-57402b00609c?format=json"), HttpWebRequest)
        response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

        Dim rawresp As String
        rawresp = reader.ReadToEnd()

        Dim jResults As JObject = JObject.Parse(rawresp)

        Dim results As List(Of JToken) = jResults.Children().ToList()

        For Each item As JProperty In results
            item.CreateReader()
            Select Case item.Name
                Case "Site"
                    Dim strResult = item.Value.ToString
                    Select Case strResult
                        Case "Gold Coast"
                            MsgBox("Gold Coast")

                        Case Else
                            MsgBox("Unable to handle " & strResult)
                    End Select
            End Select
        Next


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        If Not response Is Nothing Then response.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: [tag:json] is a simple, hierarchical textual format for exchanging data.  See: https://json.org/.  Your code uses [tag:json.net] to parse some JSON into a [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) hierarchy of JSON tokens (the JSON equivalent of LINQ to XML and `XElement`) for subsequent processing using vb.net.   Incidentally, this code looks a little sketchy, e.g. [`item.CreateReader()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreateReader.htm) is called but the return is never used, so the call is useless.

Comment: But beyond that, "please add comments to my code" is sort of off-topic for stack overflow because there is no actual problem to be solved, see [help/dont-ask].  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be more appropriate as long as your code actually works (have you tested it?), see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.  But if the code isn't working, and you [edit] your question to explain how it should work, then we should be able to help with that.

Comment: You don't really need a list, you can loop over your jResults. You need to be more specific with your questions, otherwise we can't help. You could look at some of my json answer, just to get more familiar with it. But is pretty simple really, I would advise you to use some visualizer like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ that way when you collapse the json tree, and expand it one item at a time, you can visually show how you chose/got the path for the data of the item you wanted.